# How to fetch the live changes of a website in which I have an account

Tags: notifications, backend, tracking, live

Let say I have one accout on a website, and I get some messages and emails on this account frequently. But to see the changes or any new email, updates I need to login using password, security question and one OTP authentication, which will be very annoying task sometime.

So, I want to get the updates on my phone, as soon as I get some email or any message in my website account, but I don't have access to any API or any architecture of the website.

Anyone? HOw can I proceed for this problem??

`I just want to know the process how can I approach?`

I am thinking  to just write a script which will store the user info and call in some interval and will show the updates if something changes from the previous response.

But the problem is that, I can't send multiple request, if I will send multiple request then may be website backend will throw me out or don't allow me to login for some time?

Is there any proper approach  to this problem???